# Split Array of Strings in a DataFrame into their own columns

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, explode

I have a dataframe like this:

df.show()

```
+-----+ 
|col1 | 
+-----+ 
|[a,b]| 
|[c,d]|   
+-----+
```

How to convert it into a dataframe like below

```
+----+----+ 
|col1|col2| 
+----+----+ 
|   a|   b| 
|   c|   d|  
+----+----+
```

Comment: Will the `list` be of fixed length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of your "list":

If it is of type `ArrayType()`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([['a', ["a","b","c"]], ['b', ["d","e","f"]]]), ["key", "col"])
df.printSchema()
df.show()
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
+---+---------+
|key|      col|
+---+---------+
|  a|[a, b, c]|
|  b|[d, e, f]|
+---+---------+
```

- you can access the values like you would with python using `[]`:

```
df.select("key", df.col[0], df.col[1], df.col[2]).show()
+---+------+------+------+
|key|col[0]|col[1]|col[2]|
+---+------+------+------+
|  a|     a|     b|     c|
|  b|     d|     e|     f|
+---+------+------+------+
```

- If it is of type `StructType()`: (maybe you built your dataframe by reading a JSON)

```
df2 = df.select("key", F.struct(
        df.col[0].alias("col1"), 
        df.col[1].alias("col2"), 
        df.col[2].alias("col3")
    ).alias("col"))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()

root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
+---+---------+
|key|      col|
+---+---------+
|  a|[a, b, c]|
|  b|[d, e, f]|
+---+---------+
```

- you can directly 'split' the column using `*`:

```
df2.select('key', 'col.*').show()

+---+----+----+----+
|key|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|  a|   a|   b|   c|
|  b|   d|   e|   f|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed built from JSON and it was an ArrayType. And the first part of your answer helped. The StructType in your answer though, wouldn't the contents of 'col' column be like [(col1=a),(col2:b),(col3:c)] ?

Comment: @Gadam I’m creating it out of the existing data frame. If you see that’s how I’m accessing those elements above